# how to sort selected data at php to mysql from flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

here is my code at flutter

```
void initState(){
    var url = "my web";
    String id =  widget.list[widget.index]['id_pemesanan'];
    http.post(url, body: {
        'id_pemesanan': id,
    });
    super.initState();
}
```

here is the code at my php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$id_pemesanan = $_POST['id_pemesanan'];

$queryResult = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Odr_Msk_Detail WHERE id_pemesanan = '$id_pemesanan'");

$result=array();

while($fetchData=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[]=$fetchData;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

if i change the data at `$id_pemesanan` to directly my data id in my database, it works, but if i use `$id_pemesanan` it doesnt shows anything in my listview

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnerable for SQL injections, so try to use PDO or Prepared statements. Second, try this: `$id_pemesanan = (int) $_POST['id_pemesanan'];` to make sure you have an integer in your request.

Comment: Use PostMan to test your api first. Then use requestbin to test what actual data it is sending to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your data in ascending or descending order as needed using the Order By clause.

For details you can check the following link:
https://www.guru99.com/order-by-desc-and-asc.html

How to optimize it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

However as noted by the others, your current code is vulnerable to sql injection, I would recommend reading up on MySQL prepared statements and PHP PDO.

A very nice resource for it:
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo